# Can't modify start menu at all in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

This is a fresh install.

I cannot get any changes to the start menu to reflect.
Anything I do in `Settings -> Personalization - > Start` has no effect.

Anything I pin to start or unpin from start is undone on logout or reboot.

I'm using the profile I used to setup the machine (which was offline for the duration so definitely a local account).

I'm patched to the latest patches available on Semi-Annual (Targeted) and I'm on build 1709.

I'm not sure where to look at this point.  Every time I google this issue I find people who solve it in ways that don't apply here (for example, a domain policy).

(I've had this issue on the last couple I set up at my company too, but assumed it was an issue local to there, so seeing it on a completely unrelated machine is throwing me for a loop here.)

Comment: Have you tried using the [Start Menu Troubleshooter](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/the-start-menu-is-not-working-after-upgrading-to/3ad997ca-cbaa-42a2-8df5-2d05d43cd5c0?auth=1)?

Comment: Yes, it reports that it cannot find anything wrong.  But it's the same symptoms as the users in that topic report.  Not sure what to do to remedy it at all.  I did another quick test VM (fresh install) and it has the same exact issue.